# CMake не видит компилятора

Tags: c++, c, g++, cmake, сборка

Поставил CMake (без CLang), добавил в переменную `path` путь к `cmake-3.9.2/bin`.

```
cmake -version
```

работает.

Есть `CMakeLists.txt` файл

```
#cmake

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(concentration)

option(set_clang "set clang as default compiler" 0)
option(set_gpp "set g++ as default compiler" 0)
option(cros_compile "cros compile for win32" 0)

if(${UNIX})
    message(STATUS "Unix system")
elseif(${WIN32})
    message(WARNING "Work is not guaranted")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "System not supported")
endif()

if(set_gpp)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)
endif()
if(set_clang)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)
endif()
if(cros_compile)
    set(PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}.exe)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER i686-w64-mingw32-g++-posix)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc")
endif()

message(STATUS "Project " ${PROJECT_NAME})
message(STATUS "cxx compiler " ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER})

add_definitions(-Wall -std=c++14)

include_directories(include)

set(MAIN_SRC sources/main.cpp)
file(GLOB CONCENTRATION_SRC "sources/concentration/*.cpp")

if(cros_compile)
    find_package(PDCurses REQUIRED)
else()
    find_package(Curses REQUIRED)
endif()

include_directories(${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MAIN_SRC} ${CONCENTRATION_SRC})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CURSES_LIBRARIES})
```

в общем когда запускаю командами

```
cmake
cmake -Dset_gpp=1
```

CMake пишет:

> ```
> -- The C compiler identification is unknown
> -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
>   The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:
>
>     cl
>
>   is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
>
>   To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
>   that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
>   unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
>   Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).
>
>   Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
>   variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
>   the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
>
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
>   The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:
>
>     cl
>
>   is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
>
>   To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
>   that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
>   unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
>   Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).
>
>   Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
>   variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
>   to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
>
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
> See also "../CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
> See also "../CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
> ```

Путь к компилятору есть в `path`. `g++` команда работает. Постоянно компилирую с командной строки. Пробовал в `CmakeLists.txt` указывать явный путь к `g++`. Все равно не помогает. Все пути к файлам - латиница.

В общем, нужна помощь!

Comment: А путь к `cl` есть в PATH?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan я пользуюсь MinGW как настроить работу с ним?

Comment: Можно указать для какой системы генерировать сборку: `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"` (по умолчанию у вас, похоже, cmake для visual студии пытается сгенерировать проект).

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan спасибо, помогло!

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan оформите как ответ. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Windows, судя по [исходникам](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/5f4af3e556bd266a3f827a297aacbbfb9ddb7d84/Source/cmake.cxx#L1445), CMake по дефолту (если генератор не указан явно) пробует найти (по записям в реестре) самую свежую версию Visual Studio, а если не находит, использует NMake.

Таким образом, если у вас установлена Студия (или просто остался мусор в реестре, в результате некорректного удаления студии или по другим, гораздо более серьезным причинам), то CMake будет делать проект под самую свежую из установленных Студий.

Чтобы явно указать нужный вам генератор, используйте ключик -G:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"
```